How do I get the number of dimensions (aka order or degree) of a tensor in PyTorch?
If I have a PyTorch tensor such as
t = torch.rand((2,3,4,5))

how do I get the number of dimensions of this tensor? In this case, it would be 4.

From PyTorch the number of dimensions of a tensor is stored in the .ndim attribute of the tensor, or you can call the .dim() function.
If you have
t = torch.rand((2,3,4,5))

you get the number of dimensions with
t.ndim 
# 4

or
t.dim()
# 4

